# tty disappears after the motherboard changed

Tags: tty

I had used Ubuntu 14.04 x64 bit for months until one day the old motherboard of my old computer irreversibly crashed. I had to replace the motherboard which required to replace the processor as well. The rest of the hardware remained intact. Ubuntu 14.04 was installed and configured in the very same way as for the old hardware. It works smoothly, except for one issue:

I love playing some games on Steam. It can work under the native Nouveau X.Org X server video driver, but then the game turns a sadistic torture because everything is incredibly slow and not all details are shown. As I install proprietary NVidia drivers (I tried 346.87 and 352.21), the gaming is perfect, but no tty appears at Ctrl-Alt-F1-5. Blank screen! As soon as I put Nouveau driver back, tty comes back, too. This annoying issue NEVER appeared with the old hardware: it is a direct consequence of the motherboard upgrade.

Grub modifications (uncommenting #GRUB_TERMINAL=console and

## GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480, changing to #GRUB_GFXMODE=auto, adding 'nomodeset' at the end of 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash') had no effect.

I really miss virtual terminals, but I feel I have no more ideas. Can anyone help?

Old hardware:
motherboard ASUS P7H35, processor i5 @1.33 GHz, graphics GeForce GT 740

New hardware:
motherboard Gigabyte GA-B85M-D2V, processor i5-4590 CPU @ 3.30GHz, graphics graphics GeForce GT 740.

Comment: have you tried any other tty? like tty2? Back in the day the various ttys had use specific functions, perhaps youre encountering some of that. ..

Comment: Of course I have. Same sh...t.

Comment: Evidently, I had the same issue, a while ago, and the only solution I got was to reinstall. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1522558  Anyhow, try this: http://www.computershowto.pro/2013/03/terminal-missing-in-ubuntu-when-you-press-altctrlf1-f6/

Comment: Thank you very much. The idea with 'getty' didn't work and I can understand why: if there are no terminals on the level of the kernel, then they should not reappear after the changing of video drivers. I am considering reinstalling it. The drawback of the reinstallation is that, in fact, you admit that you cannot do anything and are not going to understand why. Anyway, this might be just prudent to admit so.

Comment: [SOLVED] It was much simpler! (As it usually is). When I had the computer upgraded, the guys from the store deformed a little bit a DVI-D port of the graphic card, so I connected the display via a VGA cable. Today, just by accident I succeded to connect it with a DVI-D cable. The tty's have come back. I'm so sorry for bothering the people. :(